# Save DateTime object to SQLSRV param

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

So I have some PHP code, which is suppose to save a datetime from user input into the database.  But the correct datetime is not saved, in fact, no changes are made, what am I doing wrong?

```
 $data['sendStartTime'] = date_create_from_format('M d, Y @ h:i A', $data['sendStartTime']);


$params = array(
    array(&$data['sendStartTime'], NULL, NULL, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_DATETIME)
);

$sql = "UPDATE theTable SET sendStartTime = ? ";
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($con, $sql, $params) or die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));
```

Here is a test Data:

```
[sendStartTime] => DateTime Object
    (
        [date] => 2014-01-31 00:00:00
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => America/New_York
    )
```

After I run the code, the database sendStartTime does not reflect this change, it is still the original datetime.

Comment: "It's not working" can mean a lot of things.

Comment: It basically does not save, it stay the same value as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set the query you want to run, and you've prepared the statement, but you never actually execute it.

Try adding 
`sqlsrv_execute($stmt);`
after the `sqlsrv_prepare` call.